# log4j to write log to console and also to file

Tags: java, selenium, log4j

I use Selenium WebDriver and log4j in my Java project. I set log4j.properties as follows:

```
# Define the root logger with appender file
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, stdout, FILE

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender

# Set the name of the file
log4j.appender.FILE.File=C:/_privat/myproj/log/log.out

# Set the immediate flush to true (default)
log4j.appender.FILE.ImmediateFlush=true

# Set the threshold to debug mode
log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold=debug

# Set the append to false, overwrite
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=false

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%-20c{1}:%3L] %m%n
log4j.appender.stdout.Threshold=INFO
```

During execution I see only these lines instead of full log.

```
Starting ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.8 (681f24ea911fe754973dda2fdc6d2a2e159dd300-refs/branch-heads/3770@{#40}) on port 3320
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
jún. 14, 2019 8:26:53 DE org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
```

When execution is stopped I get all the log messages also to console, which was written to file. I need to see log also in console during execution.

Comment: What's the question ?

Comment: change this value `log4j.appender.stdout.Threshold=INFO` to `log4j.appender.stdout.Threshold=DEBUG`

Comment: @KunduK : I still can't see log messages during execution.